# android Device Administrator not open when activated for application

Tags: android

I am activating mobile device administrator from my application via firing intent.

My application open device admin page in first trial. Now I activate device admin from my application.

But when it comes to reopen(to deactivate or activate) its not opens device admin page, even my code runs those line which fires device admin.

Code for opening device admin page:

```
     ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(mContext, MGDeviceAdminReciever.class);
     Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
     intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,mDeviceAdminSample);
     intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,mContext.getString(R.string.enable_device_manager_declare));
     mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here its is, but instead of opening device admin page it will disable it internally .

```
            DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(mContext, MGDeviceAdminReciever.class);
            if (isChecked) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {

                    if (!PreferenceDataHelper.getUIEnable(mContext, PreferenceDataHelper.UNINSTALL_PROTECT_BUTTON_SETTING)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
                        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, mContext.getString(R.string.enable_device_manager_declare));
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                **mDPM.removeActiveAdmin(mDeviceAdminSample);**
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Device Administrator is disabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```